# wp_enqueue_script : how to change loading order of scripts?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I would like to know how to list all scripts loaded on a page, ranked by order and change this order.

Comment: You can do the same using depends parameter of wp_enqueue_script() function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you take a look at the source of [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_script/) (or the register-sister), then you'll see that there's the `global $wp_scripts` handling all the heavy stuff.

Basically the global is just an instance of `WP_Scripts`, which is a child of `WP_Dependency` and you can use all the magic from there if there's no higher level API available.

To see all registered, enqueued, etc. scripts, simply

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered );
```

or do the same with `enqueue`. Luckily you got one argument to actually sort your stuff: `dependencies`. So if you want to be one script loaded *after* jQuery has been loaded, simply add a dependency of `array( 'jquery' )` when registering or enqueueing your script.  That's the way you order them in WordPress: Make them dependent on each other. Btw, the dependency name *always* simply is the name it was registered with, called the "handle".